# Bash: automate backup from FTP to local linux machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

I am looking for a bash script, which can download all files from FTP and zip or tar it locally with date in the file name. In simple words: I have at home an Ubuntu machine and I want to backup my website (FTP) locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just out of the top of my head:

```
#!/bin/sh
mysite=your.site.com
rm -rf "/tmp/$mysite"
wget -m "user/pass@ftp://$mysite" && tar cvf "$mysite.`date +%Y-%m-%d`.tar" /tmp/$mysite
```